# Meaning of terra::nearest() to_id column

Tags: r, terra

I'm trying to use `R`'s `terra::nearest()` function, but I cannot understand the output format and how to actually figure out which point was nearest! Here's a simple example:

```
> dest <- terra::vect(data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 5, 5), y = c(0, 5, 0, 5), attr = 1:4), geom = c("x", "y"))
> src <- terra::vect(data.frame(x = c(3, 1, 2), y = c(2, 3, 1)), geom = c("x", "y"))
> near_ret <- terra::nearest(src, dest)
> print(near_ret)
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : points 
 dimensions  : 3, 7  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 0, 5, 0, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. :  
 names       : from_id from_x from_y to_id  to_x  to_y distance
 type        :   <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num>    <num>
 values      :       1      3      2     1     5     0    2.828
                     2      1      3     2     0     5    2.236
                     3      2      1     3     0     0    2.236
```

OK, so `to_x`, `to_y` and `distance` columns make sense to me and look correct. But `to_id` doesn't make any sense to me. I would have assumed that column would have indexes into `dest`, but it clearly does not because `dest[1, ]` is `(0, 0)` not `(5, 0)`.

My end goal here is to figure out the value of `attr` for the `dest` point closest each `src` point. How can I find the `dest` point which is closest so that I can look up it's `attr` value?

(This is using terra version `1.3-4`)

Comment: Also posted to https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/328

Comment: It looks like this is probably a real bug in `terra::nearest()`. https://github.com/rspatial/terra/pull/329 has a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in terra version `1.4-4`